# TWRP Unable to mount everytime I boot into TWRP recovery mode

Tags: twrp

After I installed TWRP and a Custom ROM everytime I boot into the Recovery Mode it says unable to mount storage or data and then I have to do the steps to fix it and then when i boot to system my files get removed

Steps I do when the TWRP can't mount:

1. I click the wipe menu
2. Then Advance Menu
3. and then I click the data and check it
4. And then I click the repair or change
5. I click change first since error 255 when I click the repair first
6. I changed it to HTX4
7. I reboot to recovery
8. I changed it back to f2fs again
9. And repair it
   10 finished the mount problem is fixed

The problem is when I boot up and then reboot to recovery again the problem is back again and the data is erased

Comment: this is no "fix" to get "access" you're simply factory resetting device each time. booting into android will automatically re-encrypt the phone, and there is no way access encrypted data in TWRP. ask the TWRP maintainer for encryption support, use another custom ROM, another recovery, or simply disable encryption in ROM at all

Comment: How do I disable encryption in ROM?

Comment: with encryption disabler

Comment: Can you send the file for it

Comment: And also the custom ROM is android 13 can I still disable it

Comment: maybe if you add the necessary information in your question